# Reformatting hierarchical JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following hierarchical JSON data retrieved from a PostgreSQL DB using PHP:

```
[{"treelevel":"1","app":"Front","lrflag":null,"ic":null,"price":null,"parentlevel":"0","seq":"27", "indexlistid":439755},
{"treelevel":"2","app":"V-Series","lrflag":null,"ic":null,"price":null,"parentlevel":"1","seq":"28", "indexlistid":439755},
{"treelevel":"3","app":"opt J56","lrflag":null,"ic":null,"price":null,"parentlevel":"2","seq":"29", "indexlistid":439755},
{"treelevel":"4","app":"R.","lrflag":"R","ic":"536-01132AR","price":"693.00","parentlevel":"3","seq":"30", "indexlistid":439755},
{"treelevel":"4","app":"L.","lrflag":"L","ic":"536-01133AL","price":"693.00","parentlevel":"3","seq":"31", "indexlistid":439755},
{"treelevel":"3","app":"opt J63","lrflag":null,"ic":null,"price":null,"parentlevel":"2","seq":"32", "indexlistid":439755},
{"treelevel":"4","app":"R.","lrflag":"R","ic":"536-01130R","price":null,"parentlevel":"3","seq":"33", "indexlistid":439755},
{"treelevel":"4","app":"L.","lrflag":"L","ic":"536-01131L","price":null,"parentlevel":"3","seq":"34", "indexlistid":439755}]
```

I need some way to reformat the data to this:

```
[{"app": "Front-V-Series-opt J56-R. R", "price": "$693", "ic": "536-01132AR"},
{"app": "Front-V-Series-opt J56-L. L", "price": "$693", "ic": "536-01132AL"},
{"app": "Front-V-Series-opt J63-R. R", "price": null, "ic": "536-01130R"},
{"app": "Front-V-Series-opt J63-L. L", "price": null, "ic": "536-01131L"}]
```

The parentlevel and treelevel are the 2 keys that make up the tree relationship.

The app value in the new format is a concatenation of the app and lrflag values from all the
nodes in one tree level + the price and ic from the deepest leaf node in the level. This is the
data visualized as a tree:

```
[
    {
        "app": "Front",
        "children": [
            {
                "app": "V-Series",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "app": "opt J56",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "app": "R. ,
                                "lrflag": "R",
                                "ic": "536-01132AR",
                                "price": "$693"
                            },
                            {
                                "app": "L. ,
                                "lrflag": "L",
                                "ic": "536-01132AL",
                                "price": "$693"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "app": "opt J63",
                         "children": [
                            {
                                "app": "R. ,
                                "lrflag": "R",
                                "ic": "536-01130R"
                            },
                            {
                                "app": "L. ,
                                "lrflag": "L",
                                "ic": "536-01131L"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried several different ways to do this but am just stuck. Here are some of the functions 
that I've attempted to modify and use to no luck. I can't even get the tree correctly built from
these.

```
function buildTree(list) {
    var map = {}, node, roots = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        map[list[i].treelevel] = i; // initialize the map
        list[i].children = []; // initialize the children
    }
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        node = list[i];
        if (node.parentlevel !== "0") {
            // if you have dangling branches check that map[node.parentId] exists
            list[map[node.parentlevel]].children.push(node);
        } else {
            roots.push(node);
        }
    }
    return roots;
}

function listToTree(data, options) {
    options = options || {};
    var ID_KEY = options.idKey || 'treelevel';
    var PARENT_KEY = options.parentKey || 'parentlevel';
    var CHILDREN_KEY = options.childrenKey || 'children';

    var tree = [],
        childrenOf = {};
    var item, id, parentId;

    for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
        item = data[i];
        id = item[ID_KEY];
        parentId = item[PARENT_KEY] || 0;
        // every item may have children
        childrenOf[id] = childrenOf[id] || [];
        // init its children
        item[CHILDREN_KEY] = childrenOf[id];
        if (parentId != 0) {
            // init its parent's children object
            childrenOf[parentId] = childrenOf[parentId] || [];
            // push it into its parent's children object
            childrenOf[parentId].push(item);
        } else {
            tree.push(item);
        }
    };

    return tree;
}

unflattenToObject = function(array, parent) {
    var tree = {};
    parent = typeof parent !== 'undefined' ? parent : {id: 0};

    var childrenArray = array.filter(function(child) {
        return child.treelevel == parent.parentlevel;
    });

    if (childrenArray.length > 0) {
        var childrenObject = {};
        // Transform children into a hash/object keyed on token
        childrenArray.forEach(function(child) {
            childrenObject[child.treelevel] = child;
        });
        if (parent.treelevel == 0) {
            tree = childrenObject;
        } else {
            parent['children'] = childrenObject;
        }
        childrenArray.forEach(function(child) {
            unflattenToObject(array, child);
        })
    }
    return tree;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the idea is to get the first element's index in the max depth `treelevel : 4` then start from there and loop backwards, making sure you don't go through the parents twice, and concatenate what you need along the way, once you reach the top level, you delete that element

wrap that in a function and call it recursively until there's no `treelevel : 4` left

```js
var data = [{
    "treelevel": "1",
    "app": "Front",
    "lrflag": null,
    "ic": null,
    "price": null,
    "parentlevel": "0",
    "seq": "27",
    "indexlistid": 439755
  },
  {
    "treelevel": "2",
    "app": "V-Series",
    "lrflag": null,
    "ic": null,
    "price": null,
    "parentlevel": "1",
    "seq": "28",
    "indexlistid": 439755
  },
  {
    "treelevel": "3",
    "app": "opt J56",
    "lrflag": null,
    "ic": null,
    "price": null,
    "parentlevel": "2",
    "seq": "29",
    "indexlistid": 439755
  },
  {
    "treelevel": "4",
    "app": "R.",
    "lrflag": "R",
    "ic": "536-01132AR",
    "price": "693.00",
    "parentlevel": "3",
    "seq": "30",
    "indexlistid": 439755
  },
  {
    "treelevel": "4",
    "app": "L.",
    "lrflag": "L",
    "ic": "536-01133AL",
    "price": "693.00",
    "parentlevel": "3",
    "seq": "31",
    "indexlistid": 439755
  },
  {
    "treelevel": "3",
    "app": "opt J63",
    "lrflag": null,
    "ic": null,
    "price": null,
    "parentlevel": "2",
    "seq": "32",
    "indexlistid": 439755
  },
  {
    "treelevel": "4",
    "app": "R.",
    "lrflag": "R",
    "ic": "536-01130R",
    "price": null,
    "parentlevel": "3",
    "seq": "33",
    "indexlistid": 439755
  },
  {
    "treelevel": "4",
    "app": "L.",
    "lrflag": "L",
    "ic": "536-01131L",
    "price": null,
    "parentlevel": "3",
    "seq": "34",
    "indexlistid": 439755
  }
];

// first go look for the max depth in the tree, if it's always four, skip this part and put var max = 4

var max = 0;

data.forEach(function(elem) {
  if (elem.treelevel >= max)
    max = elem.treelevel;
});

// implement a function to get the index of the first matched element with treelevel = max depth

function getIndex() {
  return data.indexOf(data.find((elem) => {
    return elem.treelevel == max;
  }));
}

var myTree = [];

function formObject(ndx) {
  var myObj = {};
  myObj.app = [];
  var nextTreeLevel = 3;

  // start looping from the index of the element in max depth backwards 

  for (var i = ndx; i >= 0; i--) {
    // if the next element ( backwards ) is a parent , this is to avoid going through parent's siblings
    if (nextTreeLevel == data[i].parentlevel) {
      if (data[i].ic != null) myObj.ic = data[i].ic;
      if (data[i].price != null) myObj.price = data[i].price;
      if (data[i].lrflag != null) myObj.app.push(data[i].lrflag);

      myObj.app.push(data[i].app);

      nextTreeLevel = data[i].parentlevel - 1; // prent's level
    }
  }

  data.splice(ndx, 1); // remove the lement once you're done with it

  // glue the "app" together, would be better to use array.join but it's not the same join everywhere
  myObj.app = myObj.app[4] + '-' + myObj.app[3] + '-' + myObj.app[2] + '-' + myObj.app[1] + ' ' + myObj.app[0];

  // just to fill the price with null if there is none
  if (myObj.price == undefined) myObj.price = null;

  // push the object to the result's array
  myTree.push(myObj);

  // get the index of the next element in max depth ( 4 ) 
  var nextIndex = getIndex();

  // if there's still another element in the max depth, recall the same function with it's index
  if (nextIndex > -1)
    formObject(nextIndex)
}

formObject(getIndex())

console.log(myTree);
```